# Minha lógica simples feita no className não está comparando certo (React)

Tags: javascript, react

Estou fazendo uma lógica de comparação dentro do ClassName, segue:

```
<button className={'OVERDUE' || 'CONFIRMED' || 'RECEIVED' === 'PENDING' ? 'YES' : 'NO'} onClick={ () => this.showModalEdit(payment)} >My button</button>
```

O problema do código é que ele sempre volta YES.

Comment: Estou meio confuso com o que você tentou fazer. Qual era o comportamento esperado?

Comment: Você não está comparando nada com variáveis. Monte sua lógica em um `if` primeiro e depois tente colocar no `className`, se desejar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria validar cada um dos status e colocar a pendência como: sim ou não?

```
let $status = null
let $render = null

//verifica o status e cria um JSX a partir do resultado
if (($status === 'OVERDUE') || ($status === 'CONFIRMED') || ($status === 'RECEIVED')) {
   $render = <button className="PENDING YES"> onClick={ () => 
          this.showModalEdit(payment)} > My button</button>
   } else {
       $render = <button className="PENDING NO"> onClick={ () => this.showModalEdit(payment)} > My button</button> }

//Reinderiza o objeto $ render a partir da condição
<div>
{$render}
</div>
```